# How to make real 3D videos in Blender?

Tags: 3d-view, video, stereoscopy

I have a Panasonic 3D flatscreen at home and now I want to make my own 3D videos for it.
How can I do that with Blender, without using the method of different colors (red and blue). 
It should be watchable like the footage from the blurays...

Comment: Look at the manual, it's called MultiView: https://www.blender.org/manual/render/workflows/multiview/usage.html

Comment: I know about this, but that does not create a movie file, that is watchable in real 3D.

Comment: It allows you to save a top-bottom/side-by-side stereo movie which can be converted further if needed to be watchable in real 3D but this further conversion is [out of the scope](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of this site. It's mainly dependant on your 3D screens supported formats. But every good 3D screen should be able to render side-by-side movies in 3D.

Comment: When I create a side by side movie it tells me, that the resolution is not supported...